# Cannot import Firebase in Swift app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

In attempting to learn Firebase, I followed the steps in the IOS Quickstart section of the Firebase website. I use Cocoapods and followed the steps exactly as documented. However, "import Firebase" results in a compiler error. I don't see the Framework any where but I do see the Firebase objective C files.. . By following the manual process of downloading the zip file and adding it to the project I can make it work. However, I would like to understand what I am doing wrong.
[image: Xcode Page]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You shouldn't need to use a Bridging Header.**

The Firebase SDK uses Swift module mapping, so you'll have to let CocoaPods know.

Use this podfile:

```
use_frameworks! # this allows you to use import Firebase
pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.0'
```

Then you should be able to use `import Firebase` in any Swift file.

Sometimes after opening from CocoaPods install, XCode can get confused. Do a `Cmd+K` to clean and a `Cmd+Shift+R` to rebuild. If that still is giving you errors, then restart Xcode and try the clean and build again.

Comment: Hey David - that's fine but seems not to be documented. https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html

Comment: You're right, it should be in the docs. The module mapping is a newer addition so it hasn't made its way there yet.

Comment: Hi David: I have the two commands as shown. I also used the 'Clean' command and restarted. But could not make it work.

Comment: In the tutorial (link in my comment) the reference to Firebase is implied. I do not see any 'import Firebase' anywhere is the code but the class is used.

Comment: Hi David: I was wrong regarding installation using Cocoapods. I opened the .xcworkspace from the console and did a 'Clean' and 'Build' as you suggested. Then 'import Firebase' did not issue a compile error. So essentially your answer is correct. Thhank you.

Answer (score 17):

Documentation is outdated.
I've used:

```
import FirebaseCore
```

Answer (score 9):

```
import FirebaseCore
```

and 
  `FirebaseApp.configure()` 
These are the new documented injections into FireBase in Swift, rather than what you were using. Good day, sir.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an ObjC bridging header. There are many SO tutorials about that.

Comment: I included a bridging header  but I am still getting an error. In a tutorial https://github.com/scotteg/Grocr/blob/master/Grocr/AppDelegate.swift I noticed that there is NO import to Firebase but there is a reference to the class. What else could I be missing? I am carefully looking at the code.

Comment: Which ObjC bridging header tutorial did you follow?

Comment: The header has to be added to build settings.

Comment: @Darko if there are many StackOverflow questions about it, can you link to one?

Comment: @Darko a bridging header shouldn't be needed.

Comment: @David I know no other way to do it. You?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen just search SO for "objective c bridging header"

Comment: @Dark, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

So I was having the same problem. Right now the fix is very simple, before you type import Firebase, after following the instructions, simply build your project. i.e. cmd+b, this did it for me, before doing this it does not recognize the path, no need to change the path!

Comment: Thanks @dherre3.  After hours of attempting to get this to work, your simple procedure worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. and i try to execute these code below in terminal, then it works for me. After change your pod file with pod 'Firebase'. Go to terminal:

```
$ cd yourSource
$ pod install
$ pod repo update
```

waiting it update for about 5 minutes. Then calling update pod

```
$ pod update
```

it will update Firebase and install some parts are lacked
I think it has something wrong about the version because i saw it installed ver 2.5 and when i called pod update, i was seeing it was installing ver 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you launched the project from "your_project_name.xcworkspace" file, instead of "your_project_name.xcodeproj" file. If not, your project won't find firebase.