# Cannot import Firebase sdk in Swift app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have developed demo ios application where I need to integrate `Firebase`, so I had followed the [Raywenderlitch tutorials](https://www.raywenderlich.com/109706/firebase-tutorial-getting-started) for how to integrate the `Firebase SDKs` in iOS who written by @David East.

After I had installed the `Firebase SDKs` via `cocoapods`, when I try to command-click on the `import` statement of `Firebase` in `AppDelegate.swift`(import Firebase) file, `xcode` goes to the following view. For more information please find the below screenshot.

[image]

Please find the below Podfile :

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'SampleApplication' do

pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
pod 'Koloda'
pod 'Firebase'

end

post_install do |installer|
    `find Pods -regex 'Pods/pop.*\\.h' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' 's/\\(<\\)pop\\/\\(.*\\)\\(>\\)/\\"\\2\\"/'`
end
```

Also I had also reviewed the issues on SO who answered by @David East, please find the below.

1) [Cannot import Firebase in Swift app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34468636/cannot-import-firebase-in-swift-app)
2) [Cannot Import Firebase Into Swift Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215522/cannot-import-firebase-into-swift-class)

But the solution is not worked in my case. Please help me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**
I had also tried to add the framework manually from [firebase official website for Integrate without CocoaPods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) but it still get the issues. For more information please find the below screenshot.

[image]

I had upload my sample application source code on dropbox, if you want then please review it.
**Source Code Link** : https://www.dropbox.com/s/5jr0zbnymhou94c/TestFireBase.zip?dl=0

Comment: load up Terminal and head to wherever your project is saved, then run pod update (updates all pods) then pod install (reinstalls them) and try then

Comment: I had already tried all pods update and reinstall but it does not solve.

Comment: you're working in the .workspace file now right?

Comment: yes working on .workspace file.

Comment: Firebase has gone through a major update since that tutorial was written. You may be using outdated code. In the firebase console, is your app created in the new console or the legacy console?

Comment: Try and remove all pods, install them so it's an empty pod file, and then install Firebase first and see what happens, also make sure you have your project closed when installing / modifying the pod file

Comment: @chickenparm : Thanks for your update, how can I solve it,  please guide me.

Comment: @Konsy : Thanks, I will try it but I thought it does not solve.

Comment: let me know if it does

Comment: sure I will update you.

Comment: @konsy : I had tried but still it does not solve.

Comment: @JorgeBarMza : I had followed the firebase documentation but still the get the issues.

Comment: @RamkrishnaSharma it's the pod file which is causing the issue! Let me post an answer which will fix it! Give me a moment please

Comment: @Konsy : Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RamkrishnaSharma posted for you

Comment: `pod 'Firebase'` is for the deprecated version 2.x. See my answer below for the updated pod names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase SDK heavily changed on May 16, 2016. This changed the names of the pods and their respective functionality.

The new pod name for the standard Firebase SDK is `Firebase/Core`, which includes only Firebase Analytics. If you're upgrading from the old Firebase system, you probably only need these:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'      # Firebase Analytics
pod 'Firebase/Database'  # Firebase Realtime Database
pod 'Firebase/Auth'      # Firebase Authentication
```

If you're using other Firebase functionality, refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup for other podnames. Don't forget that regardless of what you choose, you need to include `Firebase/Core`.

Comment: I had put all the pod which you had mentioned in your answer and followed the documentation but it does not solve it.

Comment: Make sure to run pod install again