# Xcode/Swift: How to import a framework without actually including 'import xxx' in file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've been following a Firebase tutorial for Swift [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2).

In the project I don't see any explicit 'import FirebaseXXX' within any of the files and was curious how this was being done.

I'm trying to get the same behavior in project but haven't had much luck yet. I have the same Bridging Header in my project, I've tried building/cleaning my project, and I've done 'pod update' and 'pod install' after adding the different pods to my Podfile.

So how exactly is this being done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the bridging header (`Grocr-Bridging-Header.h`), they import the framework there

```
#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>
```

Objective-C `#imports` that happen in the bridging header are global across swift files in the project.

If you are using the swift framework, you'll need to `import Firebase` at the top of the files to use the framework.

Also see [Cannot import Firebase in Swift app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34468636/cannot-import-firebase-in-swift-app)

Comment: I use the same bridging header as is in the project but I still need to 'import FirebaseXXX' in all of my files. Why would that be?

Comment: I don't think the tutorial you are following accurately reflects the current version of the Firebase framework

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443897/cannot-import-firebase-sdk-in-swift-app